# How to render raw html in Phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to render raw html like this ->

```
<%= raw "<noscript>\n <div style=\"width: 302px; height: 422px;\">\n </div>\n </noscript> \n\n\n" %>
```

but when I use `Edit as Html` in Chrome to get the code I see the following ->

```
<noscript>
  &lt;div style="width: 302px; height: 422px;"&gt; &lt;/div&gt;    
</noscript>
```

which is obviously not what I want. What am I missing here? Why the content inside the `noscript` is being escaped? What's the right way to render this string as html ?

Comment: This is not something I can recreate. Are you sure chrome isn't escaping? Can you grab the html file directly and inspect it? Are you using a template engine other than EEx? What phoenix and phoenix_html versions?

Comment: @ChrisMcCord Could you please pull this repo -> https://github.com/JustMikey/phoenix-test-app , open the app main page and inspect the bottom of the main container, I've added that code there and it doesn't seem to work, at least on my machine ...

Comment: @JustMichael This isn't a Phoenix issue. This is just how chrome handles `<noscript>` when you edit as html. You can see the same thing in https://jsfiddle.net/h6crtf2m/

Comment: @Gazler Yeah, looks like you are right. Thank you for help. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a Phoenix issue. This is just how chrome handles  when you edit as html. You can see the same thing in action at http://jsfiddle.net/h6crtf2m

```
<noscript><div></div></noscript>
```